# Unable to retrieve custom properties for Command (MdxScripts in AMO) when Migrating from DSO to AMO

Tags: c#, c++, ssas, smo

I am in process of Migrating from DSO to AMO for SSAS. Here is small sample of how we create a Command and add custom properties which we can later retrieve using DSO. Here is current DSO implementation in C++.

```
        CString sWAMeasureName = sMeasureName;
        CString sStatement = "Create Member CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[" + sWAMeasureName + "] as \' " + sExpression + "\', FORMAT_STRING = \'" + sFormat + "\', VISIBLE = 1";

        if (pCube->Commands->Find((const char*)sWAMeasureName))
        {
            pCube->Commands->Remove((const char*)sWAMeasureName);
            pCube->Update();
        }

        _CubeCommandPtr cubeCommand = pCube->Commands->AddNew((const char*)sWAMeasureName, sbclsRegular);
        cubeCommand->CommandType = cmdCreateMember;
        cubeCommand->Statement = (const char*)sStatement;
        cubeCommand->CustomProperties->Add((const char*)sAggrFunction, "AggrFunc", (VbVarType)8 /*vbString*/);
        cubeCommand->CustomProperties->Add((const char*)sAggrArg, "AggrArg", (VbVarType)8 /*vbString*/);
        cubeCommand->CustomProperties->Add((const char*)sSourceColumn, "SourceColumn", (VbVarType)8 /*vbString*/);
        cubeCommand->CustomProperties->Add((const char*)sNumMeasureName, "NumMeasName", (VbVarType)8 /*vbString*/);
        cubeCommand->CustomProperties->Add((const char*)sDenMeasureName, "DenMeasName", (VbVarType)8 /*vbString*/);
        pCube->Update();
```

After we migrate to AMO, i need to be able to retrieve the custom properties from command (mdxscript in AMO) object in AMO. I am unable to get them so far. what am I doing wrong here? Here is the sample code i wrote in C#.

```
var list = new List<String>();
var cube = GetCubeByName(catalog, sCube);

for (int i = 0; i < cube.MdxScripts.Count; i++)
{
    for (int m = 0; m < cube.MdxScripts.Count; m++)
        for (int c = 0; c < cube.MdxScripts[i].Commands.Count; c++)
        {
            foreach (Annotation ann in cube.MdxScripts[i].Annotations)
            {
                //Doesn't get here
            }

            foreach (CalculationProperty ann in cube.MdxScripts[i].CalculationProperties)
            {
                //Doesn't get here
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: If you script out the cube to XMLA can you see those CustomProperties? I'd love to see that snippet of XMLA which may help us tell you how to retrieve them in AMO.

Comment: Thank you Greg for pointing it out. XMLA showed no custom properties in Management studio. I found that Analysis Services stores MetaData in Analysis Repository that we had to configure for DSO. As I see it, I have two options now. Write code to read metadata from Analysis Repository or Forget about supporting cube created using DSO.